# Adjusting Bootstrap box widths around links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a custom nav bar I made using Bootstrap with 3 simple links: Home, Services, and Contact.  As it is right now, the boxes around each link are different sizes because each link contains a different amount of characters, as seen [here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/).  I've been trying to edit my code so all list items have a width of 100px, but nothing changes.  What can I do to make it so all the boxes surrounding my links are the same width.

Here's the HTML for my navigation:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top center" data-spy="affix">
  <div class="navbar-inner" data-spy="affix-top">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-top">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-arrow">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!--/.nav-->
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse collapse pull-right-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.navbar-inner-->
</div><!--/#nav /.navbar navbar-inverse-->
</div><!--/#nav-wrapper-->
```

Here's my CSS relating to the navigation:

```
.navbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding:0;
    z-index:999;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background: #390 url(../img/green-bg.png) repeat;
    border:none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0; 
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:0 2em;
    margin:0;
}
.navbar-inner {
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-inner ul.nav li {
    text-align: center;
}
    .navbar .nav > li a{
    color:white; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    text-shadow:none; 
    font-size:1.5em; 
    font-family: marvel, serif; 
    padding:.5em 1em; 
    margin:.5em 1em;
}
.navbar .nav > .active a:hover, .navbar .nav > li a:hover, .navbar .nav > .active a {
    color:white; 
    background: #390 url(../img/green-bg.png) repeat;
    text-shadow:none; 
    font-size:1.5em; 
    font-family: marvel, serif; 
    padding:.5em 1em; 
    margin:.5em 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
    padding:1em;
    margin:0;
}
#nav.affix, #nav.affix-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
#nav {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Did your issue got solved ?

Comment: @Shail I was able to change the width by setting a min-width, but now my center align is off and the text is offset to the side.

Comment: Did ya tried using "Pills" instead of the default "nav" class . I think the pills will solve your purpose and the customization will be much easier .

Answer (score 4):

Here's a jsfiddle I created for you - `http://jsfiddle.net/shail/Y928B/8/`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li>
<a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code**

```
 .nav li {
float:left;
width:7em; /*Fixes the width of all elements*/
padding:10px;
}
.nav li a:link {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
padding: 8px 8px 8px 0.8em;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;

}
.nav li a:hover {
background-color: #1c1c1c;
color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Result]

Comment: The boxes are of equal size , the text is centered . Offset to the right ?? didnt gotcha , really.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply a minimum width to the `a` elements :

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Keep it simple, if you want the link box to be bigger, modify the link element.

---

You may have to adjust the width rule to be applied only on a computer screen, check that by resizing your window, and see the [`@media` queries](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: This worked, but my center align is no longer working, so all my links appear slightly to the right of center.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Brian Do you have somewhere to show us ? There should not be a width to the parent `li` (I'm seeing that on your current link) and it should be `MIN-width` to avoid bigger elements getting cut or deported to the right.